# Mysql - GROUP BY Avoid using tempoary

Tags: mysql

The goal of this query is to get a total of unique records (most recent per IP, by IP) per ref ID.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ip), GROUP_CONCAT(ref.id)
FROM `sess` sess
JOIN `ref` USING(row_id)
WHERE sess.time BETWEEN '2010-04-21 00:00:00' AND '2010-04-21 23:59:59'
GROUP BY ref.id
ORDER BY sess.time DESC
```

The query works fine, but its using a temporary table. Any ideas?

The row_id is the primary on both tables. sess.time, sess.ip, and ref.id are all indexes.

Comment: can you add the EXPLAIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably using a temporary table because of the `GROUP_CONCAT`. But is that a problem really? Is the query too slow or do you simply dislike temporary tables?

Comment: I try to avoid temporary tables when working with so many rows (50k+ per day). I will need to pull this across days/months/years at times. I guess maybe its time to create another summary table?

Comment: If you need this for longer periods with more data than I would definately recommend creating summary table(s). I don't see a way to get this query itself much simpler/faster in MySQL. Perhaps if you order by `ref.id` that it would be able to omit the temporary table but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having trouble understanding how this query makes sense.  Why do you use `GROUP_CONCAT(ref.id)` if you have `GROUP BY ref.id`?  There can be only one value for `ref.id` per group by definition.

Also you `ORDER BY sess.time` even though `sess` could have multiple values for `time` per group.  Which row in the group do you want to use for sorting?

I agree that a query that invokes a temporary table usually has a performance issue in MySQL.  The temporary table often writes to disk, so you get an expensive disk I/O as part of the grouping & sorting.

Could you edit your question and show the table defintions (`SHOW CREATE TABLE` would be best)?  Also please describe what the query is supposed to represent.  Then we will have a better chance of giving you some suggestions about how to rewrite it.